# Расхождение результата с верным при вычислении среднего из ряда чисел

Tags: java

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести среднее из ряда чисел. Дается несколько рядов чисел, каждый из которых оканчивается *нулем*, и этот ноль не должен использоваться в решении (видимо, ноль в конце добавляют, чтобы удобно было разделять строки).

Проблема у меня в том, что значение, которое получаю в своем решении, незначительно отличается от верного ответа для каждого ряда чисел (у меня значение получается больше).

Т.е. я упустил какую-то мелочь в своем алгоритме решения:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    int result = 0;
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        do {
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(a);
            for (Integer element : list) { //получаю сумму всех элементов
                result += element;
            }
            result = result / list.size() - 1; // пытаюсь вычислить среднее

        } while (a != 0);
        System.out.print(result + " ");
        list.clear();
        result = 0;
    }
}
```

P.S. Если в строке, где я пытаюсь вычислить среднее, `list.size - 1` заключить в скобки, то выдаст `ArithmeticException`.

Пример вводных данных :

> 401 1766 40 1011 313 1038 1346 2002 1966 335 55 679 0
>   348 468 214 286 221 169 363 490 1 358 265 0

Comment: Ошибка возникает из за деления на ноль, вам нужно делить не последний индекс в списке а количество чисел, с которых нужно взять среднее арифметическое. соответственно, должно быть просто `result=result / list.size()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения среднего арифметического группы чисел нужно их сумму разделить на их количество. Причем делить нужно **итоговую** сумму на **итоговое** количество, а не после ввода каждого числа.

В итоге код получается такой:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    while (number != 0)
    {
        sum += number;
        count++;
        number = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print((sum / count) + " ");
}
```

Если нужно только среднее арифметическое, то сохранять все числа в список смысла нет.

Если результат должен быть не целочисленным, то можно рассчитать его как `double`, например так:

```
System.out.print((1.0 * sum / count) + " ");
```

И наконец, если результат должен быть округлением точного значения до ближайшего целого числа, то можно воспользоваться `Math.round`:

```
System.out.print(Math.round(1.0 * sum / count) + " ");
```

---

Если же числа нужны для чего-то ещё, то можно добавлять их в список, а среднее арифметическое считать с использованием Stream-ов из Java 8:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    while (number != 0)
    {
        numbers.add(number);
        number = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print(numbers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).average().orElse(0) + " ");
}
```

И целочисленный вариант:

```
System.out.print((int)numbers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).average().orElse(0) + " ");
```

---

Насчет `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`: на первой итерации у вас один элемент в списке. Соответственно, `list.size()` равен `1`, и деление значения `result` на `1` с последующим вычитанием `1` проходит вполне успешно. Чего не сказать о случае `result / (list.size() - 1)`, ибо в этом случае сначала из `1` вычитается `1`, а потом происходит попытка разделить значение `result` на получившийся `0`.

Comment: Благодарю за столь разжеванный ответ. Числа нужны только для среднего арифм., и первый код практически идеален, но выдает числа для некоторых строк которые отличаются от верного на 1(в некоторых случаях больше, в других меньше, а некоторые верные). У меня в задаче больше чем 2 строки чисел, обычно их около 13. Таким образом, что-то идет не так, я так и не понял с чем это связано . http://prntscr.com/i2ctm0, http://prntscr.com/i2cu2s

Comment: @ДмитрийКатан для того чтобы говорить с уверенностью, нужно увидеть не только результаты, но и входные данные, но расхождение на единицу (причем на единицу меньше, чем в верном) намекает на то, что они ожидают увидеть в результате округление до ближайшего целого. Я в середину ответа добавил такой вариант (с `Math.round`)

Comment: но ведь я привожу к int , он должен автоматически округлять до ближайшего целого, или нет?

Comment: @ДмитрийКатан приведение к `int` с помощью `(int)` или целочисленного деления округляет вниз, по аналогии с `Math.floor`. То есть и `2.1`, и `2.8` округляются до `2`

Comment: Все, с `Math.round()` приняло. спасибо